# Group of conjugation mappings isomorphic to original group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, for every $g \in G$ define $c_g: G \rightarrow G, c_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$.
Then $C_G := \{c_g \, | \, g \in G\}$ should be isomorphic to $G$. To prove this I want to show that $\phi: G \rightarrow C_G, g \mapsto c_g$ is a bijective homomorphism. It's obviously surjective and showing that it's a homomorphism is straightforward, too. But I'm stuck at showing the injectivity, any advice? Maybe this is only true for finite groups?

Comment: Why would it be an isomorphism? What happens if $G$ is abelian?

Comment: It was a statement in a book, maybe they implicitly assumed that G is a permutation group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is likely why you're stuck: it is not (necessarily) injective. To see this, consider the kernel of the homomorphism you constructed. If $c_g \in C_{G}$ is the identity, then that means $ghg^{-1} = h$ for all $h \in G$, i.e. $gh = hg$ for all $h \in G$. Thus, since any element $g \in G$ that commutes with all elements of $G$ will map to the identity under $\phi$, you can therefore see that $\ker(\phi)$ is in fact the center of $G$, $Z(G)$ (one can show this doing standard element chasing). If $G$ has a nontrivial center, then $\phi$ is not injective.

Comment: Any luck $\ker\phi=Z(G)$ in this case? Any clean cut conclusion about it?

Comment: @TroyWoo, actually now that I am thinking about it, I think $\ker(\phi)$ is exactly the center. I will check my thoughts and amend my post.